# locate and use src values contained within <li><img src=""></li> with PHP

Tags: javascript, image

Im trying to get the string value of an img tag that is contained within a li tag that I have in my code using javascript.

The goal is to get all of the text contained in the img tag.  But clearly I don't understand how to go that deep.  When I try, I

The format of the html that Im trying to extract is...

```
       <ol> 
         <li><img ....../></li>
       </ol>
```

Using what appears below, I get [object] returned instead of a string.  Any idea on how to get the actual value of the string?

```
<script> 
$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
        stop: function() {
            var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
            $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
                var index = $( "#selectable li img" );
                result.append( " #" + ( index + 1 ) );
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the image source, try

```
var src = index.attr('src');
```

You can get any other attributes in the same way.

Comment: What if I want to get the entire <img> tag?

Comment: Also, I keep on getting the same "src" value, despite there being 10 list items to select from (the src value isnt even selected, it's just the first one...)